# Eclipse Android No resource error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I have started learning android development using the eclipse IDE. I am using the book "Android application programming" by James Talbot & Justin McLean.

I have downloaded Eclipse and the Android SDK. However, when I create a new android project I get the error:

[2018-04-16 23:53:15 - OnYourBike-Chapter3] C:\Users\benjo\workspace\learningandroid\OnYourBike-Chapter3\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2018-04-16 23:53:15 - OnYourBike-Chapter3]

and another one but for Theme.AppCompat.Light.

I am very new to both eclipse and android SDK and the solutions I have read were mostly to go to "android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4 or v7 and import a library. I don't have these v4 or v7 folders. I have a bunch of folders like this:

[Folder contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAhov.png)

I have tried adding the .jar libraries from these folders, but it didn't work.
I have tried cleaning, building the project, replacing the code in the style.xml file, installing the Android Support Repository (tried installing Android Support Library, but couldn't find it).
I have gone through atleast 10 threads just on stackoverflow and couldn't fix my issue. Nothing worked.

My mainActivity.java file is full of errors, and looks like this:

[mainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GJrR.png)

The error on the import reads: "The import android.support cannot be resolved".

Here are pictures of my Android SDK Manager :

[Android SDK Manager SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOdj1.png)

[Android SDK Manager Extras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdUPz.png)

Hopefully someone can help me solve this. It is really frustrating and I have spent my whole day trying to fix this with no success.

Comment: `I have started learning android development using the eclipse IDE` -> Stop there and learn using Android Studio, eclipse is no longer supported as of maybe 3+ years. Unless you have a very valid reason to use Eclipse (you probably don’t), then I suggest you download Android Studio. https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: I want to follow the book that I am learning from. This is the reason I'm doing it with Eclipse.

Comment: @BenjaminBajic Using a 5 year book is okay if you have other programming experience. If you are a newbie, then use the other free and more up to date content available. But seriously life is easier if you are using current tools like Android Studio.

Comment: I believe it is, I do have programming experience, but not in Eclipse and Android. I got this book for free and it seemed really good to learn a few things.

Comment: It’s not and unless you manage to download all the old 5-years-ago tools (and you may!) then you will not be able to make it work “like the book says” because most of the magic to make Eclipse usable for android, relied on the Android Plugin, which hasn’t been maintained in years by Google. So, in truth, the best book you need on Android starts here: https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html (and if you really want a book, look at BigNerdRanch, Ray Wenderlich, etc.). They all have books and/or free resources. There is no such thing as “eclipse and android” experience anymore, not needed.

Comment: I have downloaded android studio and will try learning from there. Thank you for the recommendations and replies.